# javascript jquery change src of a script using a script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript script.  It has a src element to it.  This src is a url, and I would like to change it using javascript, just once to something else, or create it dynamically.

What's the best way to create a script element dynamically using javascript/jquery?

I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com"></script>
```

I want to change the url above to a different url using javascript/jquery.

Comment: don't change the src, just add a new script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A pure JavaScript way to inject a script tag (at the bottom of the  tag).

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='http://myjs.com/js.js';
```

Comment: What about if I have another js file that depends of the 'http://myjs.com/js.js'? How to avoid the undefineds?

Answer (score 3):

You tagged jQuery so it's really as simple as using [`getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/):

```
$.getScript(src, function () {
  console.log('script is loaded');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

A jQuery solution to dynamically inject a JavaScript file

```
$('<script>').attr({
    src: 'www.google.com',
    type: 'text/javascript'}).appendTo('body')
```

This will create a new script tag with a source pointing to www.google.com and append it to the body tag.

Comment: You're missing a `)` .  Should be `$('<script>').attr({
    src: 'www.google.com',
    type: 'text/javascript'}).appendTo('body')`

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using something like this:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var newScript = document.createElement('script');
newScript.src = 'http://path.to/script.js';
newScript.type = 'text/javascript';
head.parentNode.appendChild(newScript);
```