# Javascript / jQuery change script src in body and refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script which I need to change at runtime and reload changes

So the script is:

```
<body>
<script id="scriptId" src="myJsFile_1.js"></script>

//Rest of the page here


<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#buttonId").click(function() {

        //Change the script src to myJsFile_2.js and reload

    })

});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript jquery change src of a script using a script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031079/javascript-jquery-change-src-of-a-script-using-a-script)

Comment: What do you mean by reload? If you reload the page, myJsFile_1.js will be the file that is used every time. If you aren't talking about reloading the page, then why not just perform the view changes to the DOM within myJsFile_1.js when the user clicks the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#buttonId").click(function() {

        $(document.body).remove('#scriptId').append('<script id="scriptId" type="text/javascript" src="your_script_src"></script>');

    });
});
```

Comment: Got problems with the closing < in </script> ...says unclosed string literal